# How to Configure Project in Silverlight 5, Entity Framework 6, Telerik, Data Service / RIA

Tags: telerik, wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, devart

### I'm trying to configure a Silverlight Business Application with Silverlight 5 using OpenRIA at VS2013. I'm facing a big challenge.

1. There was no Silverlight Business Application Template. Some How After doing R&D I got it which Uses Open RIA.
2. When I tried to Use Entity Framework 6 with Oracle Devart After Adding NuGet package for it ADO.Net wizard doesn't allow to proceed. So i moved with Devard Wizard. Got Added.
3. Now I Tried Using WCF 5.6 Data Service No success Yet. Doesn't work at all from 5-6 weeks.
4. Now I tried Using Domain Service No Template Available After Updating Template Appeared.
5. Now I'm adding This Service No Domain Classes Show on wizard to select. Don't know come later they appeared out of the box after doing many times.
6. When it appeard added 1 service now.
   Error   2   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'AttachAsModified' and no extension method 'AttachAsModified' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\hpmsweorkspace\hpmsapp.Web\Service\HpmsDomainService.cs  49  13  hpmsapp.Web

issue appeared.
So as a whole Now I'm confuse. What I'm doing wrong?

I've an requirment like this:
I've to Build an ESRI application whose Spatial Data is In Oracle 11g it comes from Different sources. Each module interact with different Data. My Cilent want Rich appliation so we choose Telerik Silverlight UI. 
What is the best template to Use? what should be the Architecture Can Any Body Suggest Please help. I'm messed up between VS2013, DevArt, WCF RIA, Domain Service, WCF service & Validations too?

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to Use Entity Framework 6 with Oracle Devart After Adding NuGet package for it ADO.Net wizard doesn't allow to proceed. So i moved with Devard Wizard. Got Added.

When working with EDM Designer you should add the registration of EF-provider to the *.config file before adding a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project:
http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html

Entity Developer adds this registration of EF-provider to the *.config file automatically. We recommend you to use Entity Developer (Devart Entity Model, *.edml) instead of EDM Designer (ADO.NET Entity Data Model, *.edmx) because it is adjusted for working with Oracle and has an advanced functionality: http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html.

> Error 2 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'AttachAsModified' and no extension method 'AttachAsModified' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems that your context derives from ObjectContext, not DbContext (the EntityObject template was selected on the last step of the Create Model Wizard in Entity Developer). If yes, please do the following steps:

- expand the "Templates" node in Model Explorer;
- right-click the "EntityObject" template and select "Delete" from its shortcut menu;
- select "New Template" from the shortcut menu of the "Templates" node in Model Explorer and then select the "DbContext" template;
- save changes to generate the code for the model.

As for the available templates in Entity Developer, we recommend you to use these:

- DbContext – generates a strongly-typed DbContext class, persistence ignorant entity classes, and fluent mapping code for them;
- WCF RIA Domain Service – generates a WCF RIA Services domain service class;
- Data Annotations Metadata – generates Data Annotations metadata classes and decorate entity classes and properties with Data Annotations attributes that specify validation rules, data display settings, and define metadata for Windows Communication Foundation, Dynamic data, and WCF RIA Services.

Please refer to the corresponding section in the Entity Developer documentation: Template System Concepts.

Comment: When I Choose DBContext Template it Gives issue of 2 Times Defined & scope on Properties in Enity Not available

Comment: I wrote 1 Open RIA domain Service. Error 20 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet<HPMModel.AspNetUserClaim>' does not contain a definition for 'AttachAsModified' and the best extension method overload 'OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.DbContextExtensions.AttachAsModified<T>(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>, T, System.Data.Entity.DbContext)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Delasoft.Inc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\bs\authapp\authapp.Web\Services\DomainService.cs 130 13 authapp.Web

Comment: Most likely, the issue is related to the fact that you are working with the Silverlight application, which requires specially built assemblies (for example, such an assemblies are available in LinqConnect for Silverlight: http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/silverlight-database-access-with-linqconnect.html ). However, dotConnect for Oracle can not be used directly in the client part of Silverlight applications. dotConnect for Oracle can be employed in Silverlight applications, if the data access components are used at the server side.